# Как запретить ввод символов символов с клавиатуры в textBox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Пытаюсь создать калькулятор на Windows Forms, С#. Добавил кнопки для ввода чисел и следовательно требуется ограничить ввод пользователя в TextBox. 
Рассматриваю 2 варианта:

- Полностью ограничить ввод пользователя с клавиатуры.
- Ограничить ввод только для символов и букв.

НО, хоть сколько я буду рассматривать я не знаю как реализовать ни то, ни это. Прошу помочь.

Comment: Вы вопрос уже закрыли. Но я вам малось намекну. У текстбокса есть события, разные, но вам нужно событие клавиатурное. На это событие нужно подписаться и, в методе обрабатывающем это событие, проверять символы; если цифра пропускать, а если буква, то блокировать. Попробуйте реализовать это самостоятельно.

Comment: Спасибо, получилось)

Comment: Пожалуйста. Согласитесь, что вдвойне приятно решить проблему самостоятельно, чем получить готовое решение на блюде.

Comment: Никто и не спорит)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используй свойство `TextBox.ReadOnly`:

```
TextBox.ReadOnly = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
            {
                if ((e.KeyChar >= '0') && (e.KeyChar <= '9') || (e.KeyChar == '-') ||(e.KeyChar == '.')) 
                { 
                    
                    return; 
                }
e.Handled = true;
    }`
```

числа от 0 до 9 знак минуса и и точка, можно также добавить другие знаки, можно числа через if, а знаки через switch/case.
e.Handled = true; - запрещает ввод символов

```
    private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.KeyChar)
    {
        case '-':
            return;
        case '+':
            return;
    }
e.Handled = true;
    }
```